# VSTS Release Management: Is it possible to upload file back to a folder/branch?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

In my current process, I have a build management step which produces .bin files. After the build completes sucessfully, it goes through the release management step. I was wondering is it possible to, inside a task of the release management, to upload the .bin files back into a branch/folder of our VSTS repository?

Comment: Although you *can*, you *shouldn't*. Putting build outputs into source control is, in general, a very bad practice. **Why** do you want to put them into source control?

Comment: The team would like to have a central location to store the released binaries so it is easier to find. Since everyone is using VSTS, we decided to upload the binaries to a folder in VSTS. We are hoping there is a way to automate this in the release process

Comment: That's not how you should do it. Your builds publish artifacts. That's the "central location". Releases are tied to builds, builds have associated artifacts.

Comment: @WilliamHuang The answer is yes, but it's not suggested. Version control system  aims to manage the versions for the source code, not the build artifacts like .bin files. If it's necessary for you to manage the .bin files into git repo, you can push the files into a separate git repo so that the repo for source code is not polluted.

Comment: It sounds like you need to use nuget and package management instead of reference dlls.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I'll implement a different solution from your comments

Comment: @WilliamHuang If your problem has been solved, you can add your solution in an asswer, and it will also benefit others who meet similar question.